# Creating image derivatives with feeds and imagecache

Tags: feeds, media

I am using Drupal 6. I programmatically add nodes (with image field named field_kuva) into Drupal with feeds module (which I think uses drupal batch processing to add the nodes). After the batch job is ready I have to do smaller images with image cache module.

This is how I do the batching (code A):

```
$myFeed = feeds_source($feed_source);
  $config = array(
      'FeedsHTTPFetcher' => array(
          'source' => $url));
  $myFeed->addConfig($config);
  while (FEEDS_BATCH_COMPLETE != $myFeed->import());
```

After this I loop through all the nodes I added and use image cache module to do the derivatives of the original image like this (code B):

```
 $presets = imagecache_presets();

      $node = node_load($row->nid);
      if ($node) {
        foreach($presets as $preset) {

            foreach($node->field_kuva as $image) {
              $src = $image['filepath'];
              $dst = imagecache_create_path($preset['presetname'], $src);

              if (!file_exists($dst)) {
                imagecache_build_derivative($preset['actions'], $src, $dst);

              }
            }

        }
```

Now, if I run code A and code B **during the same page load**, the source image in $src doesn't yet exist and the derivatives are not created. If I run code A and then **on separate page load** run code B everything works and the derivatives are created.

What do I need to do to get both operations run during the same page load?